# Save command output only if there's output (Unix CLI)

Tags: bash, shell

I have a placeholder file and would like to override it with the output of a command only if the output is not zero length. I guess I could do `FOO="$(command)"` then `[-z $FOO]`. Is there a better way?

Comment: If the output of the command is associated to the status of it, you could just run the command and check $?.  Otherwise -z is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways, but I don't know about "better".  You could block on a read and only set up the redirection once some data come through:

```
cmd | { read j && { echo "$j"; cat; } > placeholder; }
```

(Note, if your command generates output but no newlines, this will ignore the data.)

Comment: I'd only add that `read -r` is safer since it won't interpret backslashes

Comment: @austin `read -r` is not "safer", it has different semantics.  If you don't want to interpret backslashes, then you should use `read -r`.  If you want to honor backslashes, you must not use `read -r`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the output of the command, you can run: `[ -z "$(command)" ]` directly. For example, the following prints "empty":

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$(echo -n)" ]; then
    echo "empty"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks , I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your example with `-z` will work, but you can also check if a variable is non-empty just with

```
[ "$var" ]
```

So, a simple solution could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

output="$( command )"
[ "$output" ] && echo "$output" > your_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this type of thing a lot, better make a function:

```
write_if_non_zero(){
  local msg=$1
  local file=$2
  if [[ ! -z "$msg" ]]; then
    echo "$msg" > "$file"
  fi
}
```

Then

```
write_if_non_zero "$FOO" "$FILE"
```